# Save bmp image in SQL Server database using C# and UWP

Tags: sql-server, xaml, uwp

The question: how can I save the image that is the image control (Name Photo) that is in bmp format for the database in SQL Server from UWP and C#?

class.cs

```
public BitmapImage Picture { get; set; }
```

Code C# SQL: I would be missing the equal part of the code

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@picture", SqlDbType.Image).Value =;
```

Comment: The `image` datatype has been deprecated since **2005**; don't use it any more. If you need to store binary data, use a `(var)binary`.

Comment: refers to the BitmapImage part as I can save the (var)binary image

Comment: I refer to `SqlDbType.Image` not, "bitmap image".

Comment: So the real question is how to get the bytes of that `BitmapImage` class? That type represents the bytes to draw to the screen and can't be stored anywhere. You need an Encoder to convert it to JPG, PNG or any other type you want. You can save it to a `MemoryStream` and pass the bytes to the query. If the image is large, you can save it to a temporary location, open the file as a stream and pass the stream as the parameter value

Comment: when I choose the image that is in jpg, png or gif format I convert it to bitmap to be displayed in the Image control by the as much As I can insert the bmp image (Bitmap) in the Database